# XSS via -confirm()-

Tags: xss, attack-vector

I was reading this article [here](https://respectxss.blogspot.de/2015/11/watch-out-for-based-third-party-sinks.html), in the middle I saw the author used `-confirm()-` as the payload.
I'd like to know what is this payload? I mean what's the difference between `-confirm()-` and `<script>confirm()</script>` . Why does it work while `<script>confirm()</script>` doesn't ?
It would be so much appretiated if anyone sheds some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the missing escape character `\` in the last parameter.

You can try it with an empty function:

```
<script>

function somefunction(){
//do nothing
}

somefunction( 'wskw='-confirm(1)-'');
somefunction( 'wskw='+confirm(2)+'');
somefunction( 'wskw='*confirm(3)*'');
somefunction( 'wskw='/confirm(4)/'');
somefunction( 'wskw='%confirm(5)%'');
</script>
```

It is the same like `<script>alert(1)</script>` or `<script>confirm(1)</script>`

You can test it with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v7y3x1yt/

Generally the input should be always urlencoded, like `%27` instead of `'`. They forgot to escape the second parameter.

`''` closes the string and after the `'` there can be any JavaScript code which will be executed which needs to be encapsulated in any of the following arithmetic JavaScript operators `(-, +, *, / %)`. What is happening here is a calculation with the result of the `alert()` or `confirm()` function call which has to be executed to get the result.

As the code is directly in this form in the sourcecode, it is generated on the server-side and there is the problem with the missing escaping of the parameter, there is not directly a XSS
vulnerability in the JavaScript libraries. Theoretically this unescaped code works with any function and library in JavaScript. The problem is the generation of the code on the server-side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Redirect click tracking
$.sliLinkTracker( ".redirect-link",'some_url_with_escape_characters', 'wskw='-confirm(1)-'');
</script>
```

Generally I would contact the owner of the website and disclose this to them as this is critical.